# Geocoding Service: You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API

Tags: javascript, api, maps

I was entering address in database and map work perfectlly and just suddently map crashed and autocomplete textview cannot read address. 
In console I get this error

```
Geocoding Service: You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.  For more information on usage limits and the Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage
_.Hb @ js?key=AIzaSyAPQXi7ZBZ73SPXi7JfHycSCi30thvQGCg&libraries=places&libraries=geometry:39
editmap.js:321 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined
    at editmap.js:321
    at geocoder.js:5
    at geocoder.js:3
    at qR (geocoder.js:2)
    at geocoder.js:3
    at common.js:54
    at Zl.f (common.js:15)
    at Ml.j (common.js:54)
    at Object.c [as _8pkqbn] (common.js:48)
    at GeocodeService.Search?4shdskajhdakj%2C Boston%2C America%2C 89327&7sUS&9sen-US&key=AIzaSyAPQXi7ZBZ73SPXi7JfHycSCi30thvQGCg&callback=_xdc_._8pkqbn&token=68390:1
```

Does this mean that after 24h my API key will work againg as It is, or I have to generate new one ? Please help me

Comment: This means that you have a maximum of API requests per day and that for today, you have exceeded that limit. Check what is the limit of requests.

Comment: I think 1000 per day

Comment: The official docs say this:  'Free until exceeding 25,000 map loads per 24 hours'. Apparently, it seems that you have made more than 25k of requests on the map

Comment: Most probably YES. 
Can I expect Google Maps to be working again after 24h ? 
I have to tell to my Boss what is problem :)

Comment: Yes, it is probably a temporary limit. Tomorrow should be working well;)